# Liferay 7 Select Specific Navigation Menu and Its Child Menu

Tags: navigation, liferay, portlet, portal, liferay-7

Is it possible to select a specific menu from navigation in programmatic way similar to the navigation codes in the Liferay theme?

For example, I have these pages:

- Home Services

  - Service 1
  - Service 2
- Contact

I want my main navigation to display:

**Home | Services | Contact**

Once I click Services menu, the child menus would then be displayed on my secondary navigation below the main navigation:

**Home | Services | Contact** // Using Bootstrap navbar (main)

**Service 1 | Service 2** // Another Bootstrap navbar (secondary)

So far what I can display are the menus **Home/Services/Contact**.

Thanks for any help.